# Ubuntu LTS : best practice for installing gems

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt, ruby

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server

I'm relatively new to Unix/Ubuntu.  I need to install the ruby gem `libopenssl-ruby`.

I know that Ubuntu LTS versions maintain lists of authorized package versions. `apt-get update` will sync-up the local copy of these lists , and `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade all installed packages to the latest authorized versions.

`apt-get install libopenssl-ruby` will install the `libopenssl-ruby` gem, but will this potentially pull-down a version of `libopenssl-ruby` ( and its dependencies ) that are not authorized for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

What is best practice for installing a gem on an Ubuntu LTS release?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using `apt-get` and you haven't modified any of the source repositoires from which `apt-get` pulls packages you should be completely fine in installing a `gem` in this fashion.

Going forward if you need to install lots of `gems` or need to have multiple versions of Ruby you might want to give the application `rvm` a try.

`rvm` aka. Ruby Version Manager is a tool for managing your own local versions of Ruby + Gems outside of the Ruby that comes with your distro.

Comment: Thanks for the response slm.  Could you please explain more about the source repositories from which `apt-get` pulls packages, and why/how these would have been modified ?

Comment: @BaltoStar - if you poke around on a Debian/Ubuntu box you'll see this file:  `/etc/apt/sources.list` as well as files under here: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`. These are the source repository definitions where apt will look to pull software from.

Comment: Ok, so these are the source repo defs updated by `apt-get update` ... is that what you meant by "modified" ?

Comment: @BaltoStar - correct.